# How to convert List of objects with date to array indexed with day of month?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

What is the easiest way to convert `List<DayValue>` to array, where index is day of month:

```
class DayValue 
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to do this inline, because this will be used in linq. I know I can just iterate throug items and set array values, but this needs to be done line that

```
 list.FunctionThatConvertsItIntoArray()
```

Example:

Input list:

```
{ 2012-11-01, "Value1" }
{ 2012-11-03, "Value2" }
{ 2012-11-05, "Value3" }
```

Output array:

```
1 => "Value1"
2 => null
3 => "Value2"
4 => null
5 => "Value3"
6 => null
7 => null
8 => null    
9 => null 
10 => null
11 => null
12 => null
13 => null
14 => null
15 => null
16 => null
17 => null
18 => null
19 => null
20 => null
21 => null
22 => null
23 => null
24 => null
25 => null
26 => null
27 => null
28 => null
29 => null
30 => null
```

Comment: Does you list contain unique days? Do all days always exist? Something like this didn't suffice `list.Find(x => x.Day == 5)`?

Comment: @Nagg: Type is DateTime. Sorry.

Comment: @L.B: No, all days don't exist always. They are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var days = Enumerable.Range(1, 31)
                     .Select(i => list.Find(x => x.Day.Day == i))
                     .Select(d => d != null ? d.Value : null)
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

That solves my problem:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 31).Select(
    index => (list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Day.Day == index) ?? new DayValue()).Value).ToArray();
```

Complete solution:

```
public class DayValue
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<DayValue>();

list.Add(new DayValue { Day = new DateTime(2012, 11, 1), Value = "Value1" });
list.Add(new DayValue { Day = new DateTime(2012, 11, 3), Value = "Value2" });
list.Add(new DayValue { Day = new DateTime(2012, 11, 5), Value = "Value3" });

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 31).Select(
    index => (list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Day.Day == index) ?? new DayValue()).Value).ToArray();
```